# JQuery:FullCalendar Plugin: Events are not shown in week view and day view but are shown in month view

Tags: jquery, plugins, fullcalendar

I've the following code to fetch events:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
theme: true,
slotMinutes: 10,
header: {
left: 'prev,next today',
center: 'title',
right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay',
},
defaultView: 'agendaDay',
allDaySlot: false,
editable: false,
events: "/cgi-bin/shlk/getshlkruns.pl"
});

The output from getshlkruns.pl is fairly simple json feed:
```

[{'title': 'Successful','start': 1266398223,'end': 1266398266,'url': '/shlk/cgi-bin/getshlkrunlog.pl?i=21'}]

There are several events like above (i've removed for brevity sake).

So the above events show up when am in the month view but mysteriously absent when am in week or day view.

What am doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 19):

I ran across this problem too.  The fix was to make sure each event returned in the JSON included an "allDay" name/value pair set to false.

```
[{'title': 'Successful','allDay': false,'start': 1266398223,'end': 1266398266,'url': '/shlk/cgi-bin/getshlkrunlog.pl?i=21'}]
```

Or set allDayDefault to false:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    ...
allDayDefault: false,
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 11):

Make sure that you **DO NOT** have any class on table that has overflow set to hidden. I made this mistake and wasted time on it.

`table td { 
   overflow: hidden; //Remove this to fix the issue.
}`

Answer (score 1):

Also make sure that event length must be enough that it can be displayed in slotDuration. e.g. my slotDuration is 15 minutes, my event only displayed if it has minimum 2 minutes duration.[image]

Answer (score 0):

In some cases if you are using custom css it might change the colour of your events if `allDay` is set as `false` in Month Grid view. So what I did to avoid this was changed the event JSON like this:

```
[{'title': 'Successful','allDay': currentView === 'dayGridMonth','start': 1266398223,'end': 1266398266,'url': '/shlk/cgi-bin/getshlkrunlog.pl?i=21'}]
```

where `currentView` value changes as I change the view. So if the `currentView` is dayGridMonth you have the events looking normal there despite of custom css and the week view and day view would also work perfectly.