# Some events are missing in week view and others in day view but are shown in month view

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, plugins, fullcalendar

I am syncing fullcalendar and google calendar and I have noticed that in the week view, the events sunday from 0:00 to 12:00 are missing but only for that day. If I switch to day view, it will happen for every day.

You can see the bug here: http://www.kittikun.jp/schedule2.html

Here is the source for the page:

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                events: { url:"http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/contact%40kittikun.jp/public/basic" },
                theme: true,
                header: {
                    left: 'today prev,next',
                    center: '',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                },
                allDaySlot: false,
                timeFormat: "H:mm",
                aspectRatio: 1,
                lazyFetching: false,
                firsthour: 0,
                buttonIcons: {prev: 'circle-triangle-w'},
                eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
                    if (calEvent.description) {
                        var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
                            .html(calEvent.description)
                            .dialog({
                                title: calEvent.location,
                                modal: true,
                                width: 500
                        });

                        $dialog.dialog('open');
                    }
                    return false;
                    }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

After a search on this forum, I found this topic:

[JQuery:FullCalendar Plugin: Events are not shown in week view and day view but are shown in month view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290734/jqueryfullcalendar-plugin-events-are-not-shown-in-week-view-and-day-view-but-a)

But the solution didn't work

Thanks for reading this

Comment: You have disabled allDaySlot. Please check if the missing events are AllDay events. Because allDay slot is there in Day and Week view but not in Month view. I suspect that's why you are seeing those events in month view but not in Day and Week view.

Comment: @Adil - the events are 1 hour events as far as I can see. Changing that setting would have no impact

Comment: @AdilMalik I concur, allDaySlot didn't have any effect

Comment: Fullcalendar has the issue opened for 3 years now. You can check its status with this 
[link](https://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Milestone%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=667)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran into this and I found an ugly work-around that got me through it.  Here's how I got things looking right with agendaViews:

In the initialization of the Fullcalendar, set the defaultView to 'month'.  Next, set lazyFetching to true.  Now, set the 'loading' method to change the view type. The initialization should look something like this:

```
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: ''
        },      
        defaultView: 'month',
        allDayDefault: false,
        timeFormat: '',
        allDaySlot: false,
        editable: false,
        lazyFetching: true,
        eventLimit: false,          

        events: 'https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/mycalendarURL',

        loading: function(bool) {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'changeView', 'agendaWeek' );
            }

    });
```

Believe it or not, the original 'month' view does not show up; the agendaWeek view is the only one that appears - at least as I'm testing it here at the moment in Safari on my Mac.

Basically this hack method sets the view to a view that seems to gather all the events correctly, then, the view is switched to what we really want to see.  By turning lazyFetching on, the events that are already loaded in stay loaded in.

Note that if the user navigates to far future or past events, more events will need to be loaded.  When this happens, everything goes amuck once again, even if the user navigates back to where he started.  For my application, I am limiting viewing to a small date range, so this is fine.  For other applications, this could be a problem.

Hopefully a proper solution will someday appear because I found at least three other people who have seen this problem after I scoured the internet trying to find a solution.  Hopefully my hack solution will help others until this is formally fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting

```
lazyFetching: true
```

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Worked as a charm, as long as you start into month view then went into other modes but that not how it was originally intended to work. It was supposed to use the agendaWeek by default so i've added

defaultView: "agendaWeek",

And now the sunday issue is back, although day is fixed. If go into month, it will fix it for week too.

The schedule2.html link has been updated so you can see what I mean.

Comment: I can't see any problems with it. Maybe check the support and log a bug with the developer...